# .htaccess redirecting index.php to home without redirecting subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

This is currently my entire .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  Redirect /index.php /home
  RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php?page=home
  RewriteRule ^education$ /index.php?page=home&filter=1
  RewriteRule ^skills$ /index.php?page=home&filter=2
  RewriteRule ^projects$ /index.php?page=home&filter=3
  RewriteRule ^experience$ /index.php?page=home&filter=4
  RewriteRule ^contact$ /index.php?page=contact
```

I am currently using the top redirect to redirect:
www.codeliger.com/index.php to www.codeliger.com/home to look better.
(Is there a better way of doing this?)

The issue is it is also redirecting img.codeliger.com to codeliger.com/home.

**How can I prevent the subdomain from being redirected?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can replace first rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?codeliger\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php?page=home [L]
RewriteRule ^education/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^skills/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^projects/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=3 [L]
RewriteRule ^experience/?$ /index.php?page=home&filter=4 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /index.php?page=contact [L]
```

Comment: The part after the space works. The first section does not redirect to codeliger.com/home

Comment: What is the full URL that didn't work for first rule?

Comment: Just to reiterate it will redirect to `/home` when you enter `http://www.codeliger.com/index.php` in the browser.

Comment: How can I make it redirect codeliger.com without the index.php to /home